# Getting an object to work with array_walk_recursive in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object that implements `IteratorAggregate` and `ArrayAccess`, which internally contains an array that will be generated when it is accessed.

I want to use `array_walk_recursive` on this object, but it does not seem to work. It seems that this is either impossible due to the implementation of `array_walk_recursive` or I just need to add an interface to my object. What am I missing?

Comment: It does work with [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php). So you might have luck with implementing Traversable and Countable. But OTOH most PHP array functions are a bit  recusant with array objects.

Comment: @mario: You can't directly implement `Traversable`. It is either implemented by `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate`.

Comment: It should also work with `ArrayIterator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `array_walk_recursive` operates on arrays, your object probably has to implement the [ArrayAccess](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I implemented ArrayAccess as well.

Comment: Then it will work, unless you have an error in your implementation. Remenber that for array_walk_ **recursive** to work your *offsetGet* implementation has to return an array or an object of your class.

Comment: I realized that the problem is that when I have an array mixed with my object (nested) array_walk_recursive does not work, at least with my current implementation.