# How can I format Custom Data and display in autocomplete when source is an DB

Tags: php, jquery, sql

so I'm trying to get some info in the auto-complete widget like it's shown in the JQuery UI demo [Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data), the only problem is they use a variable that they fill with the data they want to show, I instead want to access the data and the different description and stuff using a Data Base in MySQL, for this I have changed the source to use another php page that looks up the info. here is the code for the Auto-complete, I really don't understand the methods so I haven't changed it from the basic search.

This is the JS:

```
$(document).ready((function(){
            $( "#completa" ).autocomplete({
        source: "buscar.php",
        minLength: 1,
                    focus: function (event, ui){
                        $("#completa").val(ui.item.val);
                        return false;
                    };
        }));
```

This is what I have in buscar.php:

```
<?php

    $conec = mysql_connect(localhost, root, admin);
    if(!$conec)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $bd = mysql_select_db("ve_test",$conec );
        if(!$bd)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }

$termino = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//Obtener el termino que envia el autocompletar

$qstring = "SELECT name, descripcion FROM VE_table WHERE name LIKE '%".$termino."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//Solicitud a la Base de Datos

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//Realizar un LOOP sobre los valores obtenidos
{
                $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
                $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//Enviar los datos al autocompletar en codificacion JSON, Altamente Necesario.
```

?>

Comment: Why stripslashes()? Why htmlentities()? Both doesn't look like proper escaping for the context of your output.

Comment: If I'm not wrong the stripslashes is to eliminate all extra data that may come in the SQL query and the htmlentities is to format it into valid HTML.

Comment: You are wrong. The result of a query never has slashes that need to be removed, because the database is expected to only contain plain text. If YOUR database does not behave, the solution is not to fix it afterwards, but before. For htmlentities(), please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713702/php-recursive-htmlspecialchars-on-object/12713775#12713775

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will change the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the answer for the question, here it is:

in the buscar.php, I only had to add a variable with the name I wished to receive in the JQ:

```
<?php

    $conec = mysql_connect(localhost, root, admin);
    if(!$conec)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $bd = mysql_select_db("ve_test",$conec );
        if(!$bd)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }

$termino = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//Obtener el termino que envia el autocompletar

$qstring = "SELECT name, descripcion FROM VE_table WHERE name LIKE '%".$termino."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//Solicitud a la Base de Datos

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//Realizar un LOOP sobre los valores obtenidos
{
                $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
                $row['desc']=  htmlentities(stripcslashes($row['descripcion'])); //This is the line I Changed
                $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//Enviar los datos al autocompletar en codificacion JSON, Altamente Necesario.?>
```

And this is the JQ I used:

```
    $(document).ready((function(){
            $( "#completa" ).autocomplete({
        source: "buscar.php",
        minLength: 1,
                    focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#completa" ).val( ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#completa" ).val( ui.item.value );
                    $( "#completa-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
        }));
```

I hope this helps somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI autocomplete option 'source' is meant to be a String or an Array of Strings.  It can't get this from a PHP page.  You must use an AJAX call to read an output from a PHP page.  If you haven't used AJAX before you should use Google for a tutorial.  What I would do is make the PHP script output all of the data separated by a delimiter (---, for example..any thing that would not be in your list of data).  Then retrieve the data by using an AJAX call and use split() to split the output into an Array of strings by your delimiter (---).  Then this Array should work as your autocomplete's source.  To make sure you don't have a problem in your Javascript, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#completa" ).autocomplete({
        source: ["string","sample","test","preset values","thisiswhereyourarraywillgo"],
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function (event, ui){
            $("#completa").val(ui.item.val);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

If that works to predict any of those 5 words in the Array, then you have a problem with the AJAX call.

Comment: But the fact is that it does work, the only problem I have is in how do I have to format the .data structure to get the other data from the php page and what do I have to add to the buscar.php so it can send such data, sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you mean how to send buscar.php data such as $_GET['term'] you will have to use AJAX.  Try reading up on the basics of AJAX here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought it was a simpler tutorial.  http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html

Comment: the AJAX method already works, it comes implemented on the autocomplete widget, sorry....